# toggle the div on click anchor

Tags: jquery, html

I have following html:

```
<? while($arr as $data) { ?>
<td> 
 <div> 
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="status <?= $data['SUGGESTION_CD'] ?>"> 
    <img src="images/activate.gif" />
  </a> 
 </div>
</td>

<div class="remarks <?= $data['SUGGESTION_CD'] ?>" >
 <form action="status.php">
  <textarea value=""></textarea>
  <input type="submit" /> 
  <input type="button" />
 </form>
</div>
<? } ?>
```

My following scripts:

```
<style>
    .remarks { display: none; }
</style>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.status').click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault(); //to prevent default action of link tag
          $(this).parent().next('.remarks').slideToggle();
      });
});
</script>
```

With this script, all remarks div is hide. but when I click the anchor it doesn't toggle the remark div just below the anchor which is the clicked. how to toggle the remarks with class remarks when clicked the anchor which is above that div.

Comment: try $(this).parent().next('.remarks').eq(0).slideToggle()

Comment: what is that in the class <?= $data['SUGGESTION_CD'] ?>

Comment: You have a invalid markup above. you have a closing td and parent `.status` doesnot have a next elem to slidetoggle.

Comment: I can solve by the changing the markup but I want to make it works on same markup changing jquery

Comment: I would love to answer to your question. Problem could be solved in your script alone but it wouldn't make sense since your `html` needs a better treatment

Answer (score 1):

You have invalid markup. Your `DIV` is outside `TD`. Move it inside as shown below. The `TD` should move to the end of the loop to include the `DIV`.

```
<? while($arr as $data) { ?>
<td> 
 <div> 
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="status <?= $data['SUGGESTION_CD'] ?>"> 
    <img src="images/activate.gif" />
  </a> 
 </div>


<div class="remarks <?= $data['SUGGESTION_CD'] ?>" >
 <form action="status.php">
  <textarea value=""></textarea>
  <input type="submit" /> 
  <input type="button" />
 </form>
</div>

</td>
<? } ?>
```

[See demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/dwMvw/)

As per your comments - don't find workarounds. Solve the problem at the source.

Comment: Ya, I got it, it will works. But what I have to change in jquery to works on same markup.

Comment: @CodeManiac you don't need to change jQuery, you need to update the php or the code that generates the html.

Answer (score 1):

you will have to change the html code as follows:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggleDiv('<?= $data['SUGGESTION_CD'] ?>')">

<div class="remarks<?= $data['SUGGESTION_CD'] ?>" >
<form action="status.php">
<textarea value=""></textarea>
<input type="submit" /> 
<input type="button" />
</form>
</div>
```

and the script like this:

```
<script>
function toggleDiv(suggestionId) {
      $(".remarks"+suggestionId).slideToggle();
}
</script>
```

hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Your code Hierarchy is complex and not according to w3c standards, So if rather of suggesting you to change the code according to the standards (that is the right thing to do) if there is possible solutions in your code,

the one is the following

```
<? 
$i=0;
while($arr as $data) { 
?>
<td> 
 <div> 
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggleThis('<?= $i; ?>')" class="status <?= $data['SUGGESTION_CD'] ?>"> 
    <img src="images/activate.gif" />
  </a> 
 </div>
</td>

<div id="div_<?= $i; ?>" class="remarks <?= $data['SUGGESTION_CD'] ?>" >
 <form action="status.php">
  <textarea value=""></textarea>
  <input type="submit" /> 
  <input type="button" />
 </form>
</div>
<?
$i++;
} 
?>
```

And The JavaScript

```
<script>
  function toggleThis(i) {
     $("#div_" + i).slideToggle();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: this is better solution. I have also use this method but I don't know the reason the jquery script is not functioning inside the toggleThis() function but alert() is working.

Comment: also in your alert did you tried to check the value of i? like `alert(i)` ?

Answer (score 1):

What you have posted is seemed little invalid markup that's the issue which will not get the js fired event.

1. You have a closing `</td>` just before the `.remarks` div.
2. Due to this it won't get the js event you have written. (Although written correctly)

What you can do is:

```
<? while($arr as $data) { ?>
<td> 
 <div> 
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="status <?= $data['SUGGESTION_CD'] ?>"> 
    <img src="images/activate.gif" />
  </a> 
 </div>


<div class="remarks <?= $data['SUGGESTION_CD'] ?>" >
 <form action="status.php">
  <textarea value=""></textarea>
  <input type="submit" /> 
  <input type="button" />
 </form>
</div>
</td>  //<-----close it here
<? } ?>
```

then your script will work absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following javascript code:

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $('.status').on("click",function(e){
              e.preventDefault(); //to prevent default action of link tag
              $(this).parent().next('.remarks').slideToggle();
          });
    });
</script>
```